# C# list boxes padding in windows forms

Tags: c#

I am making a small point of sale app. I want to add space between product name and price. I uses `Pad Right(45)` after product name. Problem is that if product name is bigger then prices not align in same line.
please help me.

[image]

Comment: What control are you using to contain the text you input?

Comment: How about to use ListView? It can separate data with columns, and of course you can set width of each columns.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You could write method along these lines,

```
    public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
    //Takes data list and desired lenght of merged string data
    public static List<string> MergeData(List<Data> data, int maxLenght)
    {
        List<string> mergedData = new List<string>();
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            //Calculates how many spaces are needed to be inserted between Name and Price
            int numberOfSpacesNeeded = maxLenght - (d.Name.Length + d.Price.ToString().Length);
            //Builds new string with merged data
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(d.Name)
                .Append(' ', numberOfSpacesNeeded)
                .Append(d.Price.ToString());
            mergedData.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
        return mergedData;
    }
```

Second solution that doesn't require maxLength parameter

```
    public static List<string> MergeData(List<Data> data)
    {
        int maxLenght = data.Max(x => x.Name.Length + x.Price.ToString().Length) + 1;
        List<string> mergedData = new List<string>();
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            string name = d.Name;
            int numberOfSpacesNeeded = maxLenght - (d.Name.Length + d.Price.ToString().Length);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(name)
                .Append(' ', numberOfSpacesNeeded)
                .Append(d.Price.ToString());
            mergedData.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
        return mergedData;
    }
```

Both of these solutions will align Price to the right , if you want to align it to left you should find max length of the price and RightPad other prices to match its length before calculating how many spaces should you add between Name and Price.

Answer (score -1):

Can you shorten the product name?

```
        string str = "12345678901234567890";
        str = str.Remove(15);
        str = str.PadRight(45);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
```