# C# ListViewBox offset

Tags: c#, checklistbox

Is it possible to offset CheckListBox items like 21061, 22004 and 22004 in the image below?

Using the MultiColomn property does work, but it creates a spreadsheet like view, which is not exactly like the image.

[image: CheckListBox Offset]

Comment: what is it windows form or wpf, if it is a tree structure you can user TreeView

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687672/c-sharp-list-boxes-padding-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the information Muhammed Waqas Aziz.
Using a TreeView and enabling the CheckBox properties achieves the desired effect.